# Upload Data from .net Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, web-services

Sorry, if this sounds ignorant. Is it possible to SECURELY upload data from a Windows Forms app using an asp.net web service or some other method? If so, what is the general way of doing it?

I have never used web services before.

I have an IIS 6 server with .net 3.5 installed. I need to build this windows forms program, which will hold data in a local sql compact database. When the program has access to the internet, the user needs to be able to MOVE the local data to a database on the web server.

What ways can I go about doing this? Am I on the right track thinking about web services? I have also read a bit about Sync Framework, but I'm not sure if that is all that well suited for this.

Thanks for suggestions.

#### EDIT

I forgot to ask: Would WCF be a possible useful technology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just secure the web service by SSL.

WCF can be a useful technology too. You might also want to consider SQL Server merge replication.

Comment: Can you recommend one technology over the other? Also can you recommend a place to learn about it?

Comment: Replication works best if your user base is small and you do it over VPN or something. But generally, for Internet hosted stuff, I suggest hosting a WCF service over IIS (which is secured by SSL) and use WCF in your client app to connect to it. It's so easy. As for the resource, Googling gives you much!